# Could not load module libdb2.a(shr.o)

Tags: c, db2, aix

I have a C executable which depends on libdb2.a. Yet, when the executable is called, the following error popped up:

```
exec(): 0509-036 Cannot load program /my/path/my_c_exe because of the following errors:
        0509-150   Dependent module libdb2.a(shr.o) could not be loaded.
        0509-022 Cannot load module libdb2.a(shr.o).
        0509-026 System error: A file or directory in the path name does not exist.
```

Later, it is found that I should add the following env setting in the file `.profile` in my home directory:

```
LIBPATH=/db2/v84bc/sqllib/lib64
export LIBPATH
```

Yes, the issue is resolved. But I am still bewildered at the original error because the static library `libdb2.a` should be built into the c executable `/my/path/my_c_exe` in compile time. The executable should not have been looking for the static library it depends on in run time, should it? If db2 is a shared object, I can see the rationale. But for a static library, the error is beyond my understanding.

Any hints on the cause of this error? Or, though `libdb2.a` is named as a static library, it actually is a shared object? How to determine whether a library is a static one or a shared object, other than looking at the suffix (.a or .so)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions about the suffix `.a` indicating a static library is incorrect. By convention `.a` is the suffix for shared libraries, which can contain shared and static *objects*, both having the suffix `.o`. Whether an object is shared or static is indicated in its XCOFF header.

More info [in the manual](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp7a.doc%2Fgetstart%2Foverview%2Fport_aix_obj_lib.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know how to check XCOFF header of `libdb2.a`?

Comment: Did you have a chance to review the link I included in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, mustaccio. I did check the link in your answer, but not carefully enough. Now I re-examined the article and found the command to check out the library's header is `dump -ov`.